# Site not available over HTTPS with NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I followed the instructions as described in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) to setup HTTPS.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name foo.de;
    #server_name foo.de www.foo.de;
    #    rewrite ^/(.*) https://foo.de/$1 permanent;

    ssl_certificate /home/me/server/foo.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/me/server/foo.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Additionally I added a password file `etc/mypath/file.pass` with the certificate's password and referenced in the `http` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with `ssl_password_file /etc/mypath/file.pass;`.

I validated the configuration with `sudo nginx -t`. It says everything is fine. I restart the server with `sudo service nginx restart`.

I also verified with openssl (`openssl x509 -in foo.crt -text -noout`) that the CN (common name) used in the certificate is `foo.de`.

But something is not working:

```
curl https://foo.de
curl: (7) Failed to connect to foo.de port 443: Operation timed out
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The SSL port wasn't open. After `sudo ufw allow 443/tcp` it works.